# Skip Condtion if value is null

Tags: sql-server

This should be really simple; however, I cannot wrap my head around it using the CASE statement.

```
DECLARE @Test INT = NULL
SELECT *
FROM StoreImages
WHERE Quality = 1 AND Ready = @Test
```

I would like to accomplish something similar to this:

```
DECLARE @Test INT = NULL
SELECT *
FROM StoreImages
CASE @Test IS NOT NULL
  WHERE Quality = 1 AND Ready = @Test
ELSE
  WHERE Quality = 1
```

**UPDATE**

I created a schema sample for quickly testing provided answers

```
--create a temporary table
CREATE TABLE #ImagesTable(
Quality BIT,
Ready BIT)

-- insert into the temporary table
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 1); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 1); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 1); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 1); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 1); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 0); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 0); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 0); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 0); 
INSERT INTO #ImagesTable(Quality,Ready)
VALUES (1, 0);
```

- Declaring @Test as null should return all
- Declaring @Test as 1 or 0 should return half records

Comment: `WHERE (Quality = 1 AND Ready = @Test) OR Quality = 1 `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's bad practice to use ISNULL's or CASE expression around nullable parameters. Depending on the complexity of the query, it can play havoc for the optimiser, resulting in poor query plan choices.

Rather than using a CASE, use an IF to break out your query:

```
DECLARE @Test int = NULL;

IF @Test IS NULL BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM #ImagesTable IT
    WHERE IT.Quality = 1;
END ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM #ImagesTable IT
    WHERE IT.Quality = 1
      AND IT.Ready = @Test;
END
```

The first answer Sami is going to cause you problems with that OR. Regardless of the value of your @Test, a row would be returned if it has a Quality of 1.

Edit:
If you *have* to use something similar to a CASE expression, then the correct syntax would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM #ImagesTable IT
WHERE IT.Quality = 1
  AND (IT.Ready = @Test OR @Test IS NULL);
```

Comment: Yes, IF and WHILE are both available in SQL Server. They can't be used as part of a WHERE, SELECT, etc syntax, however they can still be used as logical flow operators, similar to how they are used in programming languages.

Comment: @Larnu _Sami is going to cause you problems with that OR_, cause wasn't enogh information, when the OP gives details I give the solution (if there is one).

Answer (score 3):

I would do it like:

```
DECLARE @Test INT = NULL
SELECT *
FROM #ImagesTable 
WHERE (Quality = 1 AND Ready = @Test) OR Quality = 1;
```

You can use `CASE` **if** there is a value can be in `@Test` instead of `NULL` like:

```
DECLARE @Test INT = NULL
SELECT *
FROM #ImagesTable 
WHERE Quality = 1 AND Ready = (CASE WHEN @Test IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @Test END);
```

Update:

As I can see there is only two values `0` or `1` can be in your `Ready` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM #ImagesTable 
WHERE (Quality = 1 AND Ready IN ( ISNULL(@Test, 0), ISNULL(@Test, 1) ) );
```

Here is a **[Demo](http://rextester.com/WQVNC13164)** where you can play with.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
SELECT *
FROM #ImagesTable 
WHERE Quality IS NULL
OR    (
        Quality = 1   AND
        Ready = @Test
      )
```